# ¿Cómo activar diferentes funciones MySQL con diferentes botones en formulario?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, formularios

Tengo un formulario conectado respectivamente a su base de datos MySQL el formulario tiene un botón que activa una función creada que lo que hace es incluir los datos del formulario en la base de datos, pero también tengo otra función llamada modificar que es para modificar los datos que ya se registraron previamente, como puedo crear otro botón y  que dicho botón sea independiente y solo llame a la función modificar y NO la que incluye los datos, adjunto código espero su ayuda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
        <title>PHP FORM</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="../control/c_registro.php" name="formulario" method="POST" id="form">
            <table width="200" border="0">
            <DIV class="h1"><h1>REGISTRO CONECTADO A BASE DE DATOS MYSQL</h1></DIV>
            
            <tr>
            <td>NOMBRE VIEJO</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="nombre"name="nombre" ></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>NOMBRE NUEVO</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" ></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>PASSWORD</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="pw" name="pw" ></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>CONFIRMAR PASSWORD</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="pww" ></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>EMAIL</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" ></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>enviar</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Incluir" onClick="envia(this.value)" ></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Aquí está el código de MySQL:

```
<?php
    include_once("../modelo/m_registro.php");
    $objRegistro = new registro();
    $objRegistro->setDatos($_POST["nombre"],$_POST["usuario"],$_POST["pw"],$_POST["pww"],$_POST["email"]);
    $objRegistro->incluye();
    $objRegistro->modificar();
    header("Location: ../vista/vcodigof.php");
?>
```

Aquí es donde están las respectivas funciones MySQL:

```
<?php 
include_once("m_bd.php");
class registro extends bdmysql{
    private $nombre,$usuario,$pw,$pww,$email;
    function registro(){
        $this->nombre="";
        $this->usuario="";
        $this->pw="";
        $this->pww="";
        $this->email="";
    }
    function setDatos( $nombre, $usuario, $pw, $pww, $email){
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
        $this->usuario=$usuario;
        $this->pw=$pw;
        $this->pww=$pww;
        $this->email=$email;
    }
    function incluye(){
        $NOMBRE = $_POST["nombre"];
        $USER = $_POST["usuario"];
        $PW = $_POST["pw"];
        $EMAIL = $_POST["email"];

        $sql= "INSERT INTO registro VALUES('$ID', '$NOMBRE', '$USER', '$PW', '$EMAIL')";
        return $this->ejecutar($sql);
    }

    function modificar(){
        $sql=("UPDATE registro SET NOMBRE = '$NOMBRE', USUARIO = '$USER', EMAIL = '$EMAIL' WHERE USUARIO = '$USER'");
    }
}
```

Y adjunto este otro trozo de código solo por si acaso:

```
<?php 
class bdmysql{
    private $conexion;
    function conectar()
    {
        //mysqli conecta SMBD y BD
        $this->conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "12345", "reg_users");
        if( $this->conexion )
             return true;
        else
             die( "no se conecta: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
     }
     function ejecutar($sql)
     {
        $this->conectar();
        return mysqli_query( $this->conexion, $sql ); 
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Podrías transformar el submit y cambiarlo por button, y añades otros buttons para las funciones que quieras.

Comment: Puedes ejemplificarlo porfavor?

Comment: ¿Quieres utilizar Jquery? La idea es ejecutar las funciones con ajax generando el POST en Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar el post desde Javascript, y enviar el post desde las funciones envia y modifica. Puedes consultar el API del fetch en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```html
<form name="formulario" id="form">
    <table width="200" border="0">
        <DIV class="h1"><h1>REGISTRO CONECTADO A BASE DE DATOS MYSQL</h1></DIV>
        <tr>
            <td>NOMBRE VIEJO</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NOMBRE NUEVO</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PASSWORD</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="pw" name="pw" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CONFIRMAR PASSWORD</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="pww" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EMAIL</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>enviar</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="enviar" value="Incluir" onClick="envia(this.value)" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>actualizar</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="modificar" value="Incluir" onClick="modifica(this.value)" ></td>
        </tr>
</form>


function envia(value)
{
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
    var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario');
    var pw = document.getElementById('pw');
    var pww = document.getElementById('pww');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    
    fetch("../control/c_registro.php", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'nombre': nombre,
            'usuario': usuario,
            'pw': pw,
            'pww': pww,
            'email': email
        })
    }).then( (response) => {});
}

function modifica(value){....}
```